# react typescript pass membervariables

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

My component Child has a membervariable which can change obviously.
However, I can only pass PROPS and STATES as far as I know. I know that I can pass my membervariables via PROPS or other parameters, but isnt there a more beautiful solution?

```
class Child extends React.Component<any,any> {
    private anyValue:string;
    constructor(props) {
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }
    public render() {
        return (
            <input onChange={this.change} value={this.anyValue}/>
        );
    }
    private change(e:any) {
        this.anyValue = e.target.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what state is designed for:

```
class Child extends React.Component<any,{anyValue: string}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }
    public render() {
        return (
            <input onChange={this.change} value={this.state.anyValue}/>
        );
    }
    private change(e:any) {
        this.setState({anyValue: e.target.value});
    }
}
```

Your only other option would be to use `forceUpdate`.

Comment: This is true, state is for that, however using typescript you can define membervariables, no matter why u should or should not do it, the question is: Can I readout or pass my membervariables on a generic way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "readout or pass my membervariables on a generic way".  Can you be more specific?  If you meant you want to use them to render the component, then as you saw, you can read them in the `render` method, but when a member variable changes, you need to somehow notify React that your component needs to be re-rendered.  If you use state, re-rendering is automatic when you change the state.